# How to stop Mono "Omnisharp", the C# extension in Visual Studio code from burning up my CPU at 170%+

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I've spent at least 3+ hours googling this, and everything I read in different posts online talk about IDisposable. But seeing these posts, I don't really think it would apply to me or don't know how to fix it as the answer from posts seems to be write an IDisposable then uncomment it after I finish my work. Not sure where I would write this? (which files)

It seems from opening up different files in my project, it starts to ramp up CPU utilization when I open C# files, not sure if anyone one file specifically starts the ramp up, but what's annoying is that it doesn't stop. Even if I close all the files in the IDE, the CPU still runs at 170%+ and the fan is audible. So I just quit Visual Studio Code and then re open it. I do this a couple of times a day.

Any help or advice will be very, very, very appreciated.

FYI - I was told, or read, that if I have large C# files that could do it. What's large?

If I can't find a solution, is there any other C# extension besides Omnisharp?

Comment: Which OS is this ? Can you share your settings.json for visual studio code. Is it happening for one specific project (or) every project  ?

Comment: OSX Catalina, but was happening on my old machine running Mojave. I don't have any settings.json file. Could it be named something else? I only have one app (2 projects - 1 Angular and 1 .Net Core) that I've used/developed in a while, but I don't think it was happening on any old projects. FYI - The .Net Core project has a class that references at least 30+ web service files, and it's a pretty large file. Someone said that might be the issue?

Comment: Hi, can you change the setting "csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false and then try. This guide will help you on how to change settings. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I checked it off to disable it and closed VS Code, then re opened and started typing in a C# file and Mono jumped up to 200%+ and 300%+. Did I not disable it correctly or is the problem coming from another extension or setting?

Comment: this might be better suited to the superuser SE network that SO.

Comment: Hi schuelermine. What does that mean?